# TLS Handshaking says Certificates created by AWS IoT Console are invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2, handshake

I have created a certificate at AWS IoT Console. When I run the certificates in an AWS sample on a Raspberry Pi, everything works well. My certificates are embedded into code for testing purposes, I use mbedtls_x509_crt_parse function to parse the certificates.

Now, I want to run the application on an MCU, but getting -2700 error during the handshake.
I am using the same certificates embedded into code but I get the error.

Everything seems identical between the Raspberry Pi and the MCU project. Only there is no time definition on the MCU (MBEDTLS_HAVE_TIME_DATE commented out).

I am using the mbedtls_wrapper.c implementation from the AWS IoT SDK implemented by mbedTls. I am getting"! The certificate is not correctly signed by the trusted CA" warning when I try to verify the certificates.
Problem is that I did not create the certificates, AWS did, and I am using the same certificates but getting this.

I am not an expert on this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Chun, 
Yes, I parsed the Root CA and chained with my certificate.

In my case, it seems it is about the memory. It is a small system, KBs of RAM. I just increased the Heap Size and worked. 
I would expect mbedtls to give a specific error if there is no sufficient memory.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The certificate is not correctly signed by the trusted CA

means "Root CA of your cert file is unknown to server. You need to info Root CA to server"

When you make cert file from AWS, you can get your cert file and rootCA file.

Did you use rootCA file to connect using SSL ?

ex)   ssl.connect("x.x.x.x", cert="xx.cert", rootCA = "xx.cert" , .. )

above code is just pseudo code.